# Latest PTX ISA version for sm_10

Tags: cuda, llvm, gpu, nvidia, ptx

From the NVIDIA [website](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/parallel-thread-execution/#changes-in-ptx-isa-version-4-1), I didn't find a clue regarding the PTX ISA version in which support for sm_10 is removed. From my experiments, I have an intution that it is PTX ISA 4.1 in which the support for sm_10 is removed. Or in other sense 4.0 is the latest PTX ISA version supporting sm_10. Is this correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

The last CUDA version to support `sm_10` was CUDA 6.0.

CUDA 6.5 shipped with the PTX ISA 4.1 document, and information covering `sm_10` instruction support was dropped from that document.

However CUDA 6.5 still supported `sm_11`, `sm_12`, and `sm_13`, and descriptions of supported instructions in those architectures is still included in the PTX ISA 4.1 document.